# Is "indirect object" syntactically definable or useful, in English or generally?

Tags: syntax, english, linguistic-typology

In traditional English grammar, we're taught that phrases like those boldfaced below are "indirect objects":

1. I gave the book **to Ted**.
2. I gave **Ted** the book.

But this appears to be based on semantics (namely, Recipient role) rather than syntax. In (1), **to Ted** is a prepositional phrase, which by most definitions means it can't be an object of any kind. In (2), **Ted** doesn't seem to be syntactically any different from other objects: such arguments use the objective form where this is distinct (*I gave him the book*), and they can serve as the subject in a corresponding passive construction (*Ted was given the book*).

In other languages, "indirect object" is sometimes used to refer to an obligatory argument that appears in an oblique case, as in German:

3. Ich helfe **dem Mann**. "I help the man-DAT"

Here there is syntactic justification for regarding this argument as something different from a regular object (different morphology, also can't be a passive subject), yet still regarding it as an object of some kind (given that it's an NP subcategorized for by the verb). But this is a different situation from that of English, and I can think of yet other ways that languages might treat NPs as somewhat-but-not-completely object-like (e.g., an NP that's cross-referenced by an agreement marker on the verb, but doesn't pass some syntactic test for objecthood).

So, is there a coherent syntactic definition for "indirect object" in English, in other languages, or cross-linguistically? Do syntacticians and typologists use this term at all anymore, and if so what do they mean by it?

Comment: I've never thought it was a particularly linguistic term. More folk-linguistic in that way.

Comment: @curiousdannii Well, it's certainly part of traditional grammar, and it seems linguists still use it to some extent, as in the WALS chapter linked in the answer.

Comment: There is a small error in your German: 'I help **the man**' should be 'Ich helfe **dem Mann**'.

Comment: @dumetrulo Thanks for the correction, fixed!

Comment: The way I see is that we can come up with syntactic tests for IO that will work for a specific language (e.g. English or Russian) or those that might work - albeit less accurately - for a number of languages (not necessarily genetically related) but I'm very skeptical of universal syntactic tests. see anything written by Martin Haspelmath. e.g. his 2010 paper *Comparative concepts and descriptive categories in crosslinguistic studies* https://www.jstor.org/stable/40961695

Answer (score 3):

I am by no means a lingustics expert, just fluent in German (native), English (native-level) and Spanish (native-level). As you observed, German retains enough case markers to distinguish four cases much like they existed in (say) Latin. To take up your example '1. I gave the book **to Ted**' / '2. I gave **Ted** the book', in German it would look like this:

Ich gab **Ted** das Buch.

This is equivalent to your number 2. Here, **Ted** is in the dative case but you wouldn't know that from looking at the word, since names don't get inflected in German (except in genitive case). It helps to add an article (this usage is quite colloquial, and you wouldn't usually see it in written/formal language):

Ich gab **dem Ted** das Buch.

Here the dative case is clearly visible due to the article 'dem.' Grammatically, 'dem Ted' is the indirect object in the dative case, 'das Buch' is the direct object in the accusative case (here identical to the nominative case since 'das Buch' is neuter). For emphasis or other purposes, you can freely switch the word order around without affecting the inherent meaning of the sentence, e.g.:

Ich gab das Buch **dem Ted.**

In English you no longer have a case marker to distinguish between dative and accusative case, therefore you need either a convention about where in the sentence you find the direct object, and where the indirect object, or you need to add a preposition (or another morphological marker) to distinguish the two, and make it possible to change word order.

**EDIT:** Without the article, the sentence is 'Ich gab das Buch **Ted**.' While correct, it sounds awkward, and most Germans would insert a preposition like in your sentence number 1, making it 'Ich gab das Buch **an Ted.**'

Why are the objects called direct and indirect? That is because the direct object ('das Buch') will turn into the subject of the corresponding sentence in passive voice, while the indirect object ('Ted') stays in the dative case:

Das Buch wurde **dem Ted** (von mir) gegeben.

**EDIT:** Not pertinent to the question but as an aside, there is also a passive voice using 'bekommen' as the auxiliary verb which will turn the indirect object into the subject while leaving the direct object in the accusative case:

**Der Ted** bekam das Buch (von mir) gegeben.

I am not aware of an equivalent construction in English.

**EDIT:** As far as the 'ordinary' passive goes, your sentences transform as follows:

1. I gave the book **to Ted.** => The book was given **to Ted.**
2. I gave **Ted** the book. => **Ted** was given the book.

In both cases, 'the book' is transformed from an object of the active voice to the subject of the passive voice, therefore 'the book' is the direct object in the active voice sentence. 'Ted'/'to Ted' remain in object position, and are therefore indirect objects.

Since English is in essence a Germanic language, I suppose linguists felt inclined to take the terminology that existed for German (or for Latin), and apply it to English even though it lacks syntactical markers to make sense of the distinction between direct and indirect object.

Comment: Absolutely true, except that if you passivise *"Ich gab das Buch dem Ted"*, you get *"Dem Ted wurde [von mir] das Buch gegeben"* (Ted is still dative, the book is still the subject). In your sentence, *"Der Ted bekam das Buch gegeben"*, isn't das Buch an Akkusativobjekt?

Comment: @Wilson Yes, in the sentence, *'Der Ted bekam das Buch gegeben,'* 'das Buch' is the accusative object. This construction is known as *bekommen*-Passiv. In the 'ordinary' passive (*werden*-Passiv), 'das Buch' becomes the subject in nominative case, and 'Ted' remains in dative case, same as in the active voice.

Comment: @Wilson Reading your comment again, I think you got confused as to what is what in the active voice sentence. In *'Ich gab das Buch dem Ted,'* 'ich' is the subject in nominative case, 'das Buch' is the direct object in accusative case, and 'dem Ted' is the indirect object in dative case. In *'Dem Ted wurde das Buch gegeben,'* 'dem Ted' is still the indirect object in dative case, while 'das Buch' turned into the subject in nominative case (since it is of the neuter gender, nominative and accusative case look identical). This is what happens when you transform a sentence from active to passive.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to say. *bekommen*-Passiv is not pertinent to the question because the question is about English, so I wanted to suggest that you improve your answer by using a passivisation process that befits OP's examples #1 and #2..

Comment: In "Ted was given the book", Ted does not *move to the book*.  It uses an archaic syntax, like "To Ted was given the book".  Both mean "The book was given to Ted."  Note that implicit dative needs a direct object: *"The book was given Ted."  Note that agent case marker 'by' has different meaning than preposition 'by'.  The same is true for dative case marker 'to', and 'for' is always dative (unless a conjunction).  Note archaic direct object marker 'of'.

Comment: @Wilson I edited my answer, and hope it is now more focused on the question. The *bekommen*-Passiv is not entirely off-topic though; TKR adds '3. Ich helfe **dem Mann,**' and adds that the object cannot be a subject in a passive voice sentence. This is correct for the common *werden*-Passiv but I have heard people say '**Der Mann** bekommt geholfen' (though I'll admit it's *very* colloquial, and you will probably not see that written in a formal language text).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I understand the German facts and why one might use the term indirect object there, but am still doubtful as to its application in English. Btw I think there is an error near the end where you say *In both cases, 'the book' is transformed from an object of the active voice to the subject of the passive voice* -- in your 2, the subject is *Ted*.

Comment: @ami "The book was given Ted" is acceptable to many speakers (and was once acceptable to all, I believe), but you're right that some find it ungrammatical. I don't understand the first part of your comment -- in "Ted was given the book", the subject is clearly *Ted*; there's nothing archaic about it.

Comment: @TKR The only way I can read "The book was given Ted" is as "Ted was given to the book"!

Comment: @curiousdannii The acceptability of that construction is declining, but it used to be standard (Google e.g. "given me by" for many relevant examples).

Comment: @TKR Oh it's fine if there's a "by", but a completely different matter without.

Comment: @curiousdannii So to you "The book was given Ted" is ungrammatical, but "The book was given Ted by Jill" is OK? That's interesting.

Comment: @TKR Hmm, no I don't like "The book was given Ted by Jill" either. But it's different with "me" - "This watch was given me by my sister" is okay to my ears.

Comment: @TKR - I agree that my asterisk was too strong on "The book was given Ted", but in "Ted was given the book", what is "the book" doing unmarked at the end of a passive?  I'll admit that "Ted" uses nominative case, but it's not that clear that he is subject (I should have said 'patient' - of course he is subject) rather than cryptic dative.  We are relying on semantic cues to find the recipient in both sentences.

Comment: @TKR Unfortunately you are mistaken about my number 2 at the bottom, and I can see why: since English has next to no case markers, in the absence of other cues one would construe a sentence to be in canonical SVO order, making *'Ted'* the sublect, *'was given'* the verb, and *'the book'* the object. However, if you ask, *'who/what was given'*, querying for the subject, the answer is, *'the book'*.

Comment: @dumetrulo But the answer to *Who was given the book?* is *Ted*, and *Ted* passes other subjecthood tests like verb agreement and deletion. Replacing it with a pronoun also yields a nominative *he*. It's clearly the subject.

Comment: @aml See my comment above -- *Ted* passes all subjecthood tests. Semantically of course it's a recipient, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You have different manners to define syntactic functions. There are the syntactic position and the morphological marking. These markedness' can be combined or opposite. Moreover, nothing restrains a syntactic function to one markedness. Finally, the syntactic function is determined in relation to other arguments too. So that being said, English I.O. has two markings that are used in complementarity.

First, when IO is placed in the third position and is not marked by a morpheme: S V IO O.

Second, when IO is placed in the fourth position and is marked with to-: S V O to-IO.

These conditions are sufficient not to confuse the arguments. Everything is well discriminated, because the Object, here, has other marks opposite to the Indirect Object.

As for other languages, there is WALS website where you can find more informations: https://wals.info/chapter/105

Comment: But when it's inside the prepositional phrase, it's no longer an argument of the verb phrase - I can't see what justifies it being called an object at all. And when in a prepositional phrase it can be freely moved anywhere in the sentence.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that a PP, (or a noun within a PP) can be an indirect object?

Comment: @curiousdanni In absolute terms, any clause/phrase can be an object. It will be analyzed in the same way whatever it is a noun or a prepositional phrase. From what I am aware, PP cannot be an object in English, but in other languages, it is possible. Generally, case markers came from former prepositions, so sometimes it is not easy if we are facing to a PP or IO.

Comment: @amegnunsen You just contradicted yourself... If any phrase can be an object then that includes a PP. Better to say argument though, so that it's clear you're referring to the phrase, not the embedded nominal. My point was more that a NP argument is not related to a PP argument, and the NP inside the PP is not directly related to the VP, so what right does it have to be called an object of the verb?

Comment: @curiousdannii Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying. Can you give us some examples (even artificial). Talking from facts will make our exchange easier. As far as I know, in French (Complément circonstanciel) or in English, it is impossible to confuse a PP with an object (some tests can be realized as the pronominalization). But, in OTHER LANGUAGES, a preposition can mark a direct object (Differential Object Marking), that can produce confusions especially if the verb is ambitransive (IT: S V PP / T: S V prep-O; PP = prep-O).

Comment: As far as I understand this answer, it basically restates the traditional-grammar understanding of IO (since your two constructions correspond to my 1-2). But that doesn't address my question of whether it's a linguistically coherent or useful concept.

Comment: You are saying that English IO is determined in relation to this semantic features, because, according to you, there is no morphological marker. But, it is not true, because there is a mark, it is the syntactic position. These two considerations, accounting for other arguments, are sufficient, so useful, to characterize the grammatical functions. Your third example seems to be a differential object marking with a marker borrowed to the dative as in Spanish "a".

Comment: But in English there are two distinct syntactic positions, unrelated expect by semantics. One is inside a PP and thus not what is normally called an object at all. The other is in a ditransitive construction and is clearly an object, but in what sense is it "indirect"? Of course you can choose to call it that just as a label, but that doesn't seem to generalize usefully across languages.

Comment: I am quite confused, why are you saying that "to + smt" is a PP ? "to", here, is a dative which has the same form as the preposition "to". So they are two different morphemes. The relation between them is diachronical, there has been grammaticalization.

Comment: @amegnunsen Because 'to' here is a preposition! (It's not the infinitive-to.) How could it *not* be a PP?

Comment: Are you really suggesting that *to* is a case prefix? (And also *for*?) I suspect you're trying to impose the grammar of some other language on these English constructions.

Comment: If "to" in "A give B to C" is a preposition, what kind of spatial positions there is between A and C or B and C ? you can call it a case prefix, but English is not a language with grammatical case inflections.

Comment: I don't know why you think prepositions can only express spatial relations -- that's obviously not the case. And *to* is clearly not a prefix because of its distribution; if anything, it would be a proclitic, but that too seems ruled out by e.g. *the girl I gave the book to*.

Comment: You are forgetting something important, it is the valency. A verb, as give, is ditransitive, hence two objects are necessary and have to be coded in order to be distinguished. So you cannot put in the same level a PP used with a transitive verb and which is facultative and a DAT-O used with an ditransitive verb and which is obligatory. These two constructions can share common features, but they are different. It is the same thing as "care" which can be a verb and a noun. So a linguistic analyze needs to take into consideration all the constituents of an utterance and their relations.

Comment: So a PP can't be an argument of the verb? I find this whole line of reasoning too absurd to pursue further, to be honest.

Comment: Have you ever seen a transitive verb, in English, with an argument whose the head is a preposition which has a spatial meaning? If it can be, give us an example.

Comment: Of course. *She put the pen on the table.* This is basic stuff, and in any case I'm not seeing what this tangent about PPs has to do with my original question.

Comment: I understand now why you are confused. Why is it possible to say "she put the pen down" and not possible to say "*she put the pen"

Comment: *Put* takes two arguments, of which the second can be a PP or a locational adverb like *down* (though some would actually call *down* a preposition too -- I believe CGEL takes this approach). What is your alternative analysis? More importantly, I don't understand what you're trying to establish -- even if these weren't PPs, how would that answer my original question?

Comment: My tought is can we consider verbs, as "put", as trivalent verbs? Because, we can say also "she put the book somewhere". So the nuclearity of those verbs have to be questioned. I have already answered your question about IO, I have indicated the basic elements allowing to define the arguments.