# Is “them” in “I care for them” an indirect object, a direct object, or neither sort? What exactly is the term “object” describing?

Tags: english, terminology, grammatical-object

I’m try­ing to sort out verb com­ple­ments (broadly de­fined here
as any phrase that de­ter­mines, com­pletes, or re­fines the mean­ing
of a verb) and the re­la­tions they form with verbs: ob­ject
re­la­tion, ad­ver­bial re­la­tion, or sub­ject re­la­tion.

I’ve al­ways un­der­stood **di­rect ob­jects** as phrases that
iden­tify the *thing* that re­ceives or is af­fected by the ac­tion
of the verb. (I’m not sure if this is a good def­i­ni­tion or not.)
The fol­low­ing are verb com­ple­ments with a di­rect-ob­ject
re­la­tion to their verb:

1. My mother baked **a cake**.

   [What is baked? = a cake.]
2. I need **food**.

   [What is needed? = food.]
3. She said **that the meet­ing was can­celled**.

   [What is said? = that clause.]
4. I bought **flow­ers**.

   What is bought? = flow­ers.]

The term **in­di­rect ob­ject** con­fuses me be­cause I don’t see
these as form­ing an ob­ject re­la­tion with the verb at all. They
have an ad­ver­bial re­la­tion to the verb, in­di­cat­ing the rea­son
or pur­pose of the ac­tion (why) or the di­rec­tion of the ac­tion.
Th­ese are ad­ver­bial re­la­tions, not ob­ject re­la­tions. The
so-called IO is not re­ceiv­ing the ac­tion of the verb; it is
re­ceiv­ing the verb’s ob­ject. Even when the or­der of the word
phases is in­verted, the re­la­tion is the same.

5. My mother baked a cake **for me**.

    [*For me* is ad­ver­bial.]
6. My mother baked **me** a cake.

    [*Me* is still ad­ver­bial.]
7. Jim bought flow­ers **for his wife**.

    [*For my wife* is ad­ver­bial.]
8. Jim bought **his wife** flow­ers.

    [*My wife* is still ad­ver­bial.]
9. The com­pany gave a bonus **to the team**.

    [*To the team* is ad­ver­bial.]
10. The com­pany gave **the team** a bonus.

     [*The team* is still ad­ver­bial.]

My mother didn’t bake *me*, Jim didn’t buy *his wife* (hope­fully),
and the com­pany didn’t give *the team*. None of these is an ob­ject
of the verb, so why call them ob­jects at all?

But what about sen­tences like these where the ob­ject of the
prepo­si­tion iden­ti­fies the re­cip­i­ent of the ac­tion? Are
these in­di­rect-ob­ject re­la­tions or ad­ver­bial re­la­tions?

11. She cares **for her chil­dren**.
12. Joe **apol­o­gized to Jim**.

Comment: It's neither. In "I care for them", "them" is object of the prep "for" not of the verb "care". In "My mother baked a cake for me" "for me" is not an adjunct (your adverbial) but complement of "baked".

Comment: @UbuEnglish  You may find the Wikipedia article on the dative shift helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_shift

Comment: @Greybeard But it's not helpful, since there's no dative case in modern English. To determine whether an NP is Od, Oi or object of a prep is child's play.

Comment: @Ubu English  You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about direct and indirect objects, and their functions. Adjuncts (adverbials) are semantically concerned with the circumstances of the situation -- they express such meanings as manner, spatial or temporal location, duration, condition, and so on. By contrast, the entities involved typically equate to the syntactic complements. There's a huge amount of info on the 'Net about this topic. Have you done any research?

Comment: @UbuEnglish There is no grammar I'm aware of that says such items are adverbials so why would you want to assert that they are? If you are confused about such elementary things as objects, you might consider asking your question on ELL, our learner's site which deals with such basics.

Comment: Objects are not a simple concept. In order to develop a deep understanding of the term one really needs to understand things like valency theory and transitivity, as well the linguistic use of terms such as adjunct, argument and complement, which vary in their use from theory to theory. Objects identify something that receives or is affected by the action of a verb or accept the state of relation presented by a preposition. These relations are very different from adjuncts (which in some frameworks are always adverbial) and do not function as prepositional objects.

Comment: Indirect objects always have an adverbial relation to the verb, which is why I question the use of the term object to describe them. These are all verb complements (broadly defined) and as such they take adverbial, object and subject relations with the main verb.  Calling a verb complement an object is using the relation to describe the complement. The term IO seems to be labeling an adverbial relation as an object relation.

Comment: If you're not careful, you'll push the thought that {'flowers' in 'I bought flowers' is describing the buying process} too far and have the DO an adverbial also.

Comment: You’re freely intermixing terms from distinct models of analysis in oddly incompatible fashions. You’re using the **syntactic** term
*indirect object* from traditional grammar as though it were a
**semantic** term akin to *agent, patient, recipient,* or *beneficiary* from
thematic analysis. I know of no model in which “indirect objects” are ever classified as
“adverbials”, and while not all clausal arguments need be NPs, both subject and object complements must; NB: NP ≠ PP. This question fits better on [linguistics.se] which covers the scientific study of all languages, not just English.

Comment: I think it'd be good for you to try to understand the difference between a complement and an adjunct first. e.g. http://courses.washington.edu/englhtml/engl371/Complements%20vs.%20Adjuncts.html

Comment: Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29738/is-indirect-object-syntactically-definable-or-useful-in-english-or-generally

Comment: And **one of the arguments against the adverbial status** of these constituents would be passivization in (3) below: 1. The com­pany gave a bonus to the team. 2. A bonus was given to the team. 3. The team was given a bonus.

Comment: I don't think we ever actually used the terms "direct object" and "indirect object" in my 4 year linguistics degree. I still don't really understand the difference between them (and I'm not inclined to waste time learning them.) But BillJ's first comment is absolutely correct, "them" is the argument for "for" and has no direct relationship with "care" at all.

Comment: @curiousdannii Many (but hardly all!) ditransitive verbs with NP₁-NP₂ double-object constructions (DOCs) are amenable to NP-PP alternation of NP₁. However, not all DOCs also allow for passivation of  NP₁ the way monotransitive verbs do with a single NP₀. If you give your wife a rose (gave it *to* her), your wife was given a rose. But while you can build a barn and thus have a barn that was built by you, you can't build your wife a barn (you built it *for* her) and then be able to say that *your wife was built a barn—because benefactive alternation doesn't passivize like dative alternation.

Comment: @tchrist I'm familiar with that, but I don't know which is the DO and which is the IO, and I think last time I looked at it my intuitions were wrong. I'm quite happy living in ignorance of the proper use of these terms 

Comment: @curiousdannii Given a typical English DOC word order of S-V-NP₁-NP₂, it is NP₁ people may call the IO for **some** DOCs. As AlexB alluded to elsewhere, there appears to be no syntactic test that generalizes across languages to predict what is allowed/forbidden/required, even though you can come up with ones for specific languages easily enough. They just don't usually apply to other languages apart from close neighbors, and not always then. In languages that differentially mark both objects with two distinct grammatical cases, a common pattern uses dative for the IO and accusative for the DO.

Comment: @tchrist - What a difference a forum makes. Thanks for the shift and helpful comments. I know I'm not supposed to use comments to say thanks but I feel compelled to do so.